# Accessing other files while installing from USB

Tags: arch-linux, bootable

I'm installing arch linux on an otherwise blank machine from a bootable USB, i.e. writing archlinux-2021.09.01-x86_64.iso to a USB with win32diskimager on my windows machine.

Now suppose I wanted to run a bash script to do all the disk partitioning and other installation stuff.  How can I put some scripts on the USB and access them while installing?

I've created partitions on some of the leftover space on the USB and put the scripts there (both in fat32 and ext4) with the hopes I could get to them at some point.  However, when I try to mount the partitions, I get messages saying they're already mounted or that the mount point is unavailable.

So, my questions are:

1. Can I make the approach above succeed?
2. Is there a better way to get scripts running while I'm booting from the USB?

BTW I don't know anything about computers or Linux, so any help is appreciated.

---

EDIT: I'm not trying to do a completely automated install.  Basically I want to plug in the USB, set up an internet connection, then run a script that will partition/encrypt the hard drive, mount them wherever, set up the bootloader, edit configuration files, etc., because I'm supposed to set up my machine the way someone else is dictating.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want an automated installation where you do not need to interfere and it just runs as you specified beforehand. This is called `headless install`, as it is needed for systems where you do not have a keyboard nor a monitor.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this same issue, and my solution was just to put my files on a second flash drive.

The boot media probably makes its storage inaccessible for safety reasons, meaning there's likely no easy way to access it.